# Auto-populating user info from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

Auto populate user info from database when user inputs employee number.  The same applies when the user inputs name/extension/mobile/email/

Some code is duplicated.  Is there any way to make it shorter?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#empnum").change(function () {
        var fourdigitpatrn = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        var idType = this.id;
        var myval = $.trim(this.value);
        if (myval == "" | myval.length < 3 ) return;
        if (fourdigitpatrn.exec(myval)) {
            myval ="EMP_"+myval;
            }
        if (myval.length) {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://myserver.com/helpdesk/check_json.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {type: 'empnum', term: myval},
                success: function (data) {
                    if(typeof data == "undefined" | data == null | data.length == 0){
                    alert("No Result");
                    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
                    return};
                    //console.log(data);
                    $("#empnum").val(data[0].empnum);
                    $("#ext").val(data[0].extension);
                    $("#omobile").val(data[0].omobile);
                    $("#pmobile").val(data[0].pmobile);
                    $("#ename").val(data[0].ename);
                    $("#name").val(data[0].empnum);
                    $("#email").val(data[0].email);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ext").change(function () {
        var extpatrn=/^[0-9]{2,11}$/;
        var idType = this.id;
        var myval = $.trim(this.value);
        if (!extpatrn.exec(myval))
        {
        alert ("2~11 digits needed");
        return;
        }
        if (myval == "" | myval.length < 2 ) return;
        if (myval.length) {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://myserver.com/helpdesk/check_json.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {type: 'ext', term: myval},
                success: function (data) {
                    if(typeof data == "undefined" | data == null | data.length == 0){
                    alert("No Result");
                    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
                    return};                
                    //console.log(data);
                    $("#empnum").val(data[0].empnum);
                    $("#ext").val(data[0].extension);
                    $("#omobile").val(data[0].omobile);
                    $("#pmobile").val(data[0].pmobile);
                    $("#ename").val(data[0].ename);
                    $("#name").val(data[0].empnum);
                    $("#email").val(data[0].email);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

//similar script for auto populate on omobile/pmobile/email input
...
...
...
```

Comment: `if (myval == "" | myval.length < 3 ) return;` could be simplified to `if (myval.length < 3) return;`

Answer (score 1):

given that you duplicate nearly the whole `$.ajax()` call you can extract it into a function and add a parameter where it differs::

```
function doAjax(dataType, myval){
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://myserver.com/helpdesk/check_json.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {type: dataType, term: myval},
        success: function (data) {
            if(typeof data == "undefined" | data == null | data.length == 0){
            alert("No Result");
            document.getElementById("form1").reset();
            return};
            //console.log(data);
            $("#empnum").val(data[0].empnum);
            $("#ext").val(data[0].extension);
            $("#omobile").val(data[0].omobile);
            $("#pmobile").val(data[0].pmobile);
            $("#ename").val(data[0].ename);
            $("#name").val(data[0].empnum);
            $("#email").val(data[0].email);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use a closure to avoid excessive DOM queries for all those `$('#')` selectors... and possibly the constant values in the `$.ajax` parameters, too